# Xamarin Forms iOS Renderer - ToolBar Standard Icons

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer

I can create a simple Tab Renderer which will update my Forms ToolBarItems to use the built in iOS icons like below.

`NavigationController` is only NOT `NULL` in `ViewWillAppear` If I try it in `ViewDidLoad`, it is `NULL`.

The problem with this is you get a flash of the TabBar Item text before it gets replaced with the actual icon.

Is there a different place I should be intercepting the ToolBar behavior?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(TabRenderer))]
namespace Cellar.iOS.Renders
{
    public class TabRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var list = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

            foreach (var item in NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (item.Title.ToLower() == "add")
                {
                    var newItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add)
                    {
                        Action = item.Action,
                        Target = item.Target
                    };

                    list.Add(newItem);
                }

                if (list.Count > 0)
                    NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = list.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move the `base.ViewWillAppear(animated);` to the end

Comment: This does not work, thanks though.

Comment: Do you get this flash on simulator or real device?

Comment: Real device. It's because on ViewDidLoad it's already stamped "Add" text,  then it's replacing with the iOS +

Comment: @valdetero's answer seems the most correct here. It seems strange to customize TabbedRenderer for the items that appear in the UINavigationBar. Instead, you should customize the NavigationRenderer and use it for the the NavigationPage you are wrapping a content page in.

Answer (score 1):

override `OnElementChanged` method:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.NewElement!= null)
        {
            var list = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

            // Your code goes here
        }
    }
```

Comment: this isn't working. NavigationController is NULL at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should override the `PushViewController` and inherit from `NavigationRenderer` method. Here is what I am using in my application:

```cs
public class CustomToolbarRenderer :  NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        base.PushViewController(viewController, animated);

        List<UIBarButtonItem> newItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

        foreach (UIBarButtonItem i in TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems)
        {
            if (i.Title != null)
            {
                if (i.Title.Equals(Constants.Toolbar.Add))
                {
                    var newItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
                    newItem.Action = i.Action;
                    newItem.Target = i.Target;

                    newItems.Add(newItem);
                }
                else if (i.Title.Equals(Constants.Toolbar.Camera))
                {
                    var newItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera);
                    newItem.Action = i.Action;
                    newItem.Target = i.Target;

                    newItems.Add(newItem);
                }
                else if (i.Title.Equals(Constants.Toolbar.Delete))
                {
                    var newItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Trash);
                    newItem.Action = i.Action;
                    newItem.Target = i.Target;

                    newItems.Add(newItem);
                }
                else
                    newItems.Add(i);
            }
            else
                newItems.Add(i);
        }

        TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = newItems.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work for tab switching. See my example app above.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code at the end or after the execution of the required code block...

```
return base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
```